Gas Pipe Material Type Allowed?
What type of material is allowable for Natural Gas line in a water heater installation ?
Is Galvanized pipe allowed ?
What kind of pipe is in the picture attached?
Can you provide links to acceptable or documentation : USA, Florida ..

Here is the Pipe Removed

This is what I want to replace it with:


Try a different picture with softer lighting. The flash glare makes it hard to guess the pipe type. Could be very clean/shiny and the fittings might be painted painted black iron pipe, could be galvanized, really can't be sure from this picture.

The Pipe is not black - it looks like galvanized but I cant be sure.

@Ecnerwal I updated the post with pictures of the pipe removed and the item that I want to replace it with.
